# Different GUI definitions in a WPF for different customers

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a project which is customized for different customers, only in the UI. The code is exactly the same for all.

Right now, I copy the whole project to get a different UI for the customer (button alignment, mostly). Is it possible to swap only the UI definitions / specify which to use during build, so I do not need to copy the whole project?

Something like:

```
UI_cust1
UI_cust2
UI_cust3
...
```

Build with

```
UI_cust2
```

Comment: you probably want to use the factory pattern

Comment: Do you mean localization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx ?

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638054/conditional-compile-in-xaml

Comment: If the underlying code is the same why not use themes for the customers?

Comment: Do not put your signature at the end of the message nor apologize if the question sounds silly... No questions are silly but some answers do :)

Comment: thanks for the responses so far, i guess factorys would not be the way to go.
it is also not about localisation, it is only Button re-positioning, one customer wants the print button in the top left corner the other in bottom right, and green

Comment: In addition to Dreamwalkers comment, you might want to start reading about theming/styling [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

Comment: you need to refactor your customers

Comment: so the way to go would be multiple xaml files packaged in a ResourceDictionary and then select it based on the customer-
I#ll read up on that, and thanks for pointing me in this direction, would have never looked that way.

Comment: You should use an IOC container and store the configuration in a XML file.  Each configuration file maps an interface to a concrete implementation which is customer specific.
In that way you can provide different configuration files for different customers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a configuration provider type of class which reads values from an XML file?

You can then edit the XML per customer.

I think if you create the provider as a data source and then include a converter which takes a key as a parameter to return the specific value, you should be able to create keys for each property you want to control.

I have done similar in the past as a localisation and theming solution and it worked. I haven't got code immediately to hand unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make it a habit to use an [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (Invertion of Control) container in all your projects. It forces you to use [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), which gives you a more modular architecture.

Most [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) containers support XML files for registering dependencies.
In that way you only need to change the XML configuration file for different customers. Voilà, you now have a different behavior/appearance of your application for each customer.

As a bonus, your application will be easier to test. Preferable you use [TDD](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDrivenDevelopment.html)  (Test Driven Development) while building your application, which will make the whole IOC/DI experience feel very natural.

A good IOC container to start with is [AutoFac](http://autofac.org/), a very simple, yet powerful container.