# Select XAML file based on build configuration (Visual Studio 2022, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Using Visual Studio 2022, C#, WPF, .NET Framework 4.7.2 project.

Is there any way to select XAML files at build time, such as based on either build configuration or compilation symbols, or anything else?

The use case: My now mature product was designed to run on a 2K landscape screen, all the UI layout is done in XAML and it auto-adjusts to screen sizes to a reasonable degree.  However, I was just given the requirement to make a version that runs on an 800x1200 portrait screen.  So, I'm going to have to completely re-design the layout of the screen, BUT it will have all the same objects and functionality.  The layout changes are so drastic, and the complexity of the UI is such that it only makes sense to select completely different XMAL.  I used the idea [in the 2nd post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638054/conditional-compile-in-xaml), to essentially chop my XAML file in half, copy/paste to the second half and change the layout, but because this is a runtime check, at compile time I get a zillion "*xyz is already defined...*" due to the duplicate objects with the same name, so unfortunately it didn't work for my case.  Are there any other ideas short of creating a whole new Visual Studio project with new XAML files but sharing .cs files with the original project?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean run-time? You should detect the screen or let the user select a layout. Then dynamically load the related resource dictionary and merge it into the App.xaml resource dictionary. Depending on the build action you can retrieve XAML files using the APIs of `ResourceManager`, or `Application`, or `Assembly`, or open the file from the filesystem. Then load it using the `XamlReaeder`, so that you have the final `ResourceDictionary` instance that you can add to the application's merged dictionray.

The following example is concept or pseudo code:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<ResourcDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultLayoutResources.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourcDictionary>
```

**DefaultLayoutResources.xaml**

```xml
<ResourcDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultLayoutControlStyles.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultLayoutControlTemplates.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourcDictionary>
```

**PortraitLayoutResources.xaml**

```xml
<ResourcDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="PortraitLayoutControlStyles.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="PortraitLayoutControlTemplates.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourcDictionary>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
private ResourceDictionary currentLayoutResources;

protected override async void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
{
  // Obtain from database, settings file etc.
  var layoutMode = LayOutMode.Portrait;

  if (layoutMode is LayoutMode.Portrait)
  {
    var uri = new Uri("PortraitLayoutResources.xaml");
    StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStreameManager(uri);
    await using Stream resourceStream = streamResourceInfo.Stream;
    var xamlReader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();
    xamlReader.LoadCompleted += OnXamlLoaded;
    this.currentLayoutResources = (ResourceDictionary)xamlReader.LoadAsync(resourceStream);
  }
}

private void OnXamlLoaded(object? sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  // Remove the default layout
  this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0);

  this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(this.currentLayoutResources);
}
```

### Making the `MainWindow` content dynamic

`Window` is a `ContentControl` and therefore supports data templating. You define each `DataTemplate` (e.g. one for each layout style) in a  resource dictionary of the actual layout.

Each layout style must have its own root resource dictionary (see example above). Then organize the resources the way you want and merge them into their related root dictionary.
For example, the portrait mode layout is defined by the *PortraitLayoutResources.xaml* resources. You merge all resources that belong to that layout style to the resource dictionary of *PortraitLayoutResources.xaml*. Like shown in the above example. All you need are styles and templates.

Then you have to differentiate between static and dynamic layout. The static layout references the dynamic layout resources using `{Dynamicresource}`. The resource keys must be the same across all layout styles. This way the static layout can use fixed resource keys. But the resource that they reference will change dynamically, e.g. based on the layout style. You can search for articles and information about theming in WPF. All this is highly dynamic so that the user can switch between layouts while the application is running.

The following example shows a working concept to switch the content of the `MainWindow` at runtime:

[github example](https://github.com/BionicCodeStackoverflow/dynamic_MainWindow_layout.git)

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:LayoutStyleResourceKeys.MainWindowStyleKey}}">

</Window>
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultLayoutResources.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**DefaultLayoutResources.xaml**
The root resource dictionary for the default layout.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultLayoutMainWindowResources.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**DefaultLayoutMainWindowResources.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <DataTemplate x:Key="MainWindowContent">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                 Text="Default mode layout"
                 FontSize="24" />

      <Rectangle Grid.Row="1"
                 Height="400"
                 Width="400"
                 Fill="Orange" />
      <Button Grid.Row="1"
              Content="Change layout"
              Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ChangeLayoutCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{x:Static local:LayoutMode.Portrait}"
              Width="100"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="{x:Static local:LayoutStyleResourceKeys.MainWindowStyleKey}"
         TargetType="local:MainWindow">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource MainWindowContent}" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**PortraitLayoutResources.xaml**
The root resource dictionary for the portrait layout.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="PortraitLayoutMainWindowResources.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**PortraitLayoutMainWindowResources.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <DataTemplate x:Key="MainWindowContent">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                 Text="Portrait mode layout"
                 FontSize="24" />

      <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
               Height="400"
               Width="400"
               Fill="Orange" />
      <Button Grid.Row="1"
              Height="50"
              Content="Change layout"
              Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ChangeLayoutCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{x:Static local:LayoutMode.Default}"
              Width="100"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="{x:Static local:LayoutStyleResourceKeys.MainWindowStyleKey}"
         TargetType="local:MainWindow">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource MainWindowContent}" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**LayoutStyleResourceKeys.cs**

```cs
public sealed class LayoutStyleResourceKeys
{
  // Define a resource key for each dynamic resource i.e. each resource that appear in each layout style
  public static ComponentResourceKey MainWindowStyleKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(LayoutStyleResourceKeys), nameof(MainWindowStyleKey));
}
```

**LayoutMode.cs**

```cs
public enum LayoutMode
{
  Default = 0,
  Portrait
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand ChangeLayoutCommand { get; } 
    = new RoutedCommand(nameof(MainWindow.ChangeLayoutCommand), typeof(MainWindow));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var changeLayoutCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      MainWindow.ChangeLayoutCommand, 
      ChangeLayoutCommandExecuted, 
      CanExecuteChangeLayoutCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(changeLayoutCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteChangeLayoutCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = e.Parameter is LayoutMode;

  private async void ChangeLayoutCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var layoutMode = (LayoutMode)e.Parameter;
    Uri resourceUri = layoutMode switch
    {
      LayoutMode.Portrait => new Uri("PortraitLayoutResources.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
      _ => new Uri("DefaultLayoutResources.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
    };

    await LoadLayoutAsync(resourceUri);
  }

  private async Task LoadLayoutAsync(Uri uri)
  {
    StreamResourceInfo resourceStreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
    await using Stream bamlResourceStream = resourceStreamInfo.Stream;
    bamlResourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using var bamlReader = new Baml2006Reader(bamlResourceStream);
    var resources = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(bamlReader);
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0);
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resources);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. Instead of just the resources file, can I do the same thing with the entire, for example, MainWindow.xaml?  Compile time is OK. I need to change more than the styles, I need to physically relocate everything to different places. For example I have video, tables, buttons, etc.. for the big screen these things are spread out, on the little screen the video will take the full screen and everything will be on top of the video in different places. I need to change the actual layout. Xaml is not my forte so I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: This solution allows you to switch layout at runtime. Do you use MVVM? The final solution depends on how you are handling views. The main idea is to define every layout that has to be dynamic via Style and DataTemplate. The Window class is a ContentControl. This means you can move the XAML layout to a DataTemplate, which would leave the MainWindow.xaml file blank (only the root element remains). I have updated the answer and posted a working example that switches the  content of the MainWindow at runtime based on different set of resources (theme).

Comment: [github](https://github.com/BionicCodeStackoverflow/dynamic_MainWindow_layout.git)